# $.ajax() file uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I upload image in jQuery function $.ajax()? After that I want to handle it on Servlet by [FileUpload library](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

This is form:

```
<form id="avatarUploadForm" action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input name="data" id="file" type="file"><br>
                    <input id="selectFileButton" type="button" value="Select"><br>
                    <input id="uploadButton" type="button" value="Upload"><br>
                </form>
```

I have the $.ajax() method:

```
$('#uploadButton').click(function() {
    var $form = $('#avatarUploadForm');
    var jsonFormData = $form.serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
        data : { 'file' : jsonFormData },
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'multipart/form-data',
        dataType : 'text',
        url : 'upload',
        success: function(){
            alert('uploaded');
        }
    });
});
```

And FileUpload method, which must parse my request. It's in UploadServlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

How do I convert data from form into HttpServletRequest request?

Comment: Be more specific as to what your problem is. SO is not a resource for tutorials nor a code writing service.

Comment: You have general issue ! seems you want to learn that with course not with question ! search, try your self, then if you have a problem you can ask if you didn't find solution.

Comment: @user1048261 see my post below, that's how I got it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you asked with ajax.
Here is a very good guide to uploading without refreshing the page, achieving the functionallity of "uploading with ajax"

[upload-image-using-hidden-iframe](http://www.akchauhan.com/upload-image-using-hidden-iframe/)

Answer (score 0):

you could load it in a canvas, use `toDataURL()` method and send the base64 string encoded value. This will work only on modern browser (thus no older IE)